# App crashes on Android kitkat OS

Tags: crash, android-4.4-kitkat, sqlcipher

Some of my apps published on play store getting crashed on android version 4.4 and onwords
Same apps worked on other versions of Android.

Is this issue related to os or something else?

Comment: Well, why is it crashing?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the issue is related to the os. From version to version features can change and old tools can no longer be supported. I recommend you look at the update log and see which old features you used that may no longer be supported.

Comment: I think this issue is because I used sqlcipher to protect database.

Comment: Can you post the crash report/stack trace for further debugging?